# Adjacent values for a 2d array (java)

Tags: java, arrays

Hi im trying to get all neighbors or adjacent values that are equal, in a 2d array I've searching a lot but the answers are not the adequate for me
example:

```
`|1|0|1|`
`|0|1|1|`
`|0|1|0|`
```

total adjacent: 4

```
int rowLimit = grid.length;
    int columnLimit = grid.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            for(int x = Math.max(0, i-1); x <= Math.min(i+1, rowLimit); x++) {
                for(int y = Math.max(0, j-1); y <= Math.min(j+1, columnLimit); y++) {
                    if(x != i || y != j) {
                        adj++;
                    }
                }
            }       
        }
    }



    System.out.println("Total adjacent:" + ady);
```

Comment: Walk through your example manually on paper, then translate to code.  If the code still doesn't work use a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another algorithm (in my opinion more simple than yours):

```
int[][] array = {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}};
int counter = 0;

int rowLimit = array.length;
int colLimit = array[0].length;

for (int r = 0; r < rowLimit; r++)
{
  for (int c = 0; c < colLimit; c++)
  {
    if ((c+1 < colLimit) && (array[r][c] == array[r][c+1]))
      counter++;

    if ((r+1 < rowLimit) && (array[r][c] == array[r+1][c]))
      counter++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution:

```
    int[][] array = {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}};

    int rowLimit = array.length;
    int columnLimit = array[0].length;

    int actualValue;
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < rowLimit; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < columnLimit; j++) {
            actualValue = array[i][j];
                for(int x = Math.max(0, i-1); x <= Math.min(i+1, rowLimit-1); x++){
                    for(int y = Math.max(0, j-1); y <= Math.min(j+1, columnLimit-1); y++){
                        if(x != i || y != j){
                            if(actualValue == array[x][y] && (Math.abs(x-i) + abs(y-j) == 1))
                                sum++;
                        }
                    }

            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Total adjacent: " + sum/2);
```